# Printing an List without brackets, without quotations, without commas and additional spacing

Tags: python

I have a list of attributes, attrlist[], that I have been appending strings to throughout my code. How do I print this list without brackets, quotations, and commas, and with proper spacing? Here's what I mean:

Current code:

```
print('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, attrlist)))
```

My output:

```
[1, bomb, C4, red, evil, yup]
```

I would like the programs to output:

```
1   bomb            C4        red        evil yup ...
```

The beginning of '1' to the space before 'bomb' is 4 spaces
The beginning of 'bomb' all the way to the last space before 'C4' is 16 spaces.
The beginning of 'C4' all the way to the last space before 'red' is 10 spaces.
The beginning of 'red' to the space before 'evil' is 11 spaces.

The array will change, so '1' might be '222' but still take up a total of 4 spaces. Same thing with bomb, C4, red (aka name, location, color). After that, however, the keywords don't have to be spaced, simply listed with a space in between.

Thank you so much for any help. It is greatly appreciated. By the way, I'm doing this for a tool organization system mounted on a raspberry pi, running python 2.7.10.

Comment: Theres more the question why should you do this. The format you want for output makes no sense. But special wishes can be fulfilled only by special methods, the easy way is always only for defaults. @Ben has a good answer that shows how to do your printing the long way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the brackets and commas are easy enough to get rid of, just get rid of them in your code.

```
print(' '.join(map(str, attrlist)))
```

But since you want custom spacing, you should look at [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). It uses a special [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

```
attrs = [1, 'bomb', 'C4', 'red', 'evil', 'yup']
print('{0:<4}{1:<16}{2:<10}{3:<11}{rest}'.format(*attrs[:4], rest=' '.join(attrs[4:])))
# Note in earlier versions of py2 you have to refer to format arguments by index or key, {} won't work
```

Comment: My understanding is that OP has an unknown number of keywords at the end of the list so a slight modification: `print("{0:<4d}{1:<16s}{2:<10s}{3:<11s}{rest}".format(*attrlist[:4], rest=' '.join(attrlist[4:])))`

Comment: @achampion that's probably not a bad assumption, and it doesn't break the current behavior. On a side note, any reasons why one should explicitly the type when it's the default behavior? Especially for strings, 's' is the only option.

Comment: Zen of Python: 'Explicit is better than implicit.' :) I have no good reason.

Comment: @achampion that's fair. I mean, I do that with the aligns anyway. '<' is the default behavior for most non-numerical objects, but I can almost never remember that.

Comment: FYI the field_name in the format string in 2.7 is also optional, e.g. `"{}"` works fine in 2.7, just not in early versions. `f(*args, otherarg)` is also illegal in py3.

Comment: @achampion shows what I know about 2.7 haha, I haven't really used 2.x since 2.6 was the latest release. Also I'm not quite sure why I thought an unnamed arg after a star expression was legal in py3, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

This will not by any means be efficient, but here's a solution:

```
attrlist = [1, 'bomb', 'C4', 'red', 'evil', 'yup', 'puppy'] #this list needed a puppy
lengthlist = [4, 16, 10, 11]

ans = ''
for attr, length in zip(attrlist, lengthlist):
    ans += format(attr, '<{}'.format(length))

ans += ' '.join(map(str, attrlist[len(lengthlist):]))

print(ans)
```

You can see the string formatting rules in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Your comment about `zip` doesn't make any sense. `zip(x, y)` will always stop when either `x` or `y` runs out.

Comment: @Blckknght: I didn't realize. Let me edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: Just a little tidbit, the str.format method is smart enough to recognize something like `'{attr:<{length}}'.format(attr='hi', length=5)`

Comment: Thanks. Clear to see and understand.